# Validation constraint violation: occurrence violation in element 'wsdl:operatemessage'

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, soapui

I am trying to test the `webservice` part of an application. After importing the **wsdl** in **SOAPUI**, when I ran it after providing all the necessary inputs it throws Validation constraint violation error. Can someone please suggest what on earth causes this error? Have been playing with the inputs for hours thinking that some inputs might be causing this problem, but no luck.
Below is my soap request, can someone please help me how to resolve this?

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsdl="http://ws.company.com/companyMessageAPI/3.0/wsdl">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <wsdl:MessageRequest>
         <wsdl:operateMessage>         
            <wsdl:analytics>LOGGEDIN=Y;SENTMESSAGE=Y;</wsdl:analytics>
            <wsdl:userDetailContext>
               <wsdl:userName>username</wsdl:userName>
            </wsdl:userDetailContext>
         </wsdl:operateMessage>
         <wsdl:status>true</wsdl:status>
          <wsdl:association>association1</wsdl:association>
      </wsdl:MessageRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Can you share the wsdl with the request schema? And also the soap fault response returned by your WS? `:)`

Comment: @albciff If you don't mind, can you come to StackOverflow Chat? so that I can share

Comment: now I can't, however I think that it's better to update your question to share the information with everyone. This way you've more possibilities to get various and more  accurated answers `:)`

Comment: @albciff I understand and I would like to have more possibilities for my question getting answered, but I cannot publicly open the WSDL as it might be against app policies which was why I asked you to join some SO room if you can. It's okay if you cannot, thanks for your time. If you can tell me alternative way to share, I will check if I can.